# How to get confusion matrix of Tensorflow hub model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, confusion-matrix, tensorflow-hub

I have trained a model based on transfer learning via [Tensorflow Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub). I have been looking at many places for hints on producing Confusion matrix but I haven't been able to get to the right solution.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

The last thing I tried was to write the results in an Excel sheet but I couldn't find a formula for the multi-class computation of confusion matrix in Excel.

Any help will be great!!

Comment: There is nothing specific to TF (or TF-Hub) regarding the computation of confusion matrices. Once you get the predictions for your data, just take any "standard" confusion matrix computation (e.g., for python [sklearn's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)), feed the labels and predictions to it and gt the matrix out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **tf.math.confusion_matrix** function.
It computes the confusion matrix from predictions and labels.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix.

**Example:**

```py
my_confusion_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=[1, 2, 4], predictions=[2, 2, 3])
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(my_confusion_matrix))

# Prints #
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]]

# Labels are assumed to be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] thus resulting in 5X5 confusion matrix
```